# Calculating the max of $\sin(x) + \sin(y) + \sin(z)$

Tags: trigonometry

For a given number $n$ , $$3 \le n \le 3\cdot 10^6 $$
How can I find maximum value of $$ \sin x + \sin y + \sin z $$
where $$ x + y + z = n $$
and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive integers.

I have already tried using Lagrange's as described at [Calculating $\max$ and $\min$ of $\sin(x) + \sin(y) + \sin(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153374/calculating-the-max-and-min-of-sinx-siny-sinz), but it was solved for radian. How can I extend that for my problem?